# Python try-except with of if else

Tags: python, refactoring, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
    try:
        pk = a_method_that_may_raise_an_exception()
    except:
        method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()
    else:
        if pk:
            process_pk()
        else:
            method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()
```

This could be written as:

```
    try:
        if a_method_that_may_raise_an_exception():
            process_pk()
        else:
            method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()
    except:
        method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()
```

I am not happy that the method `method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()`
appears twice, i.e in else of both if and try...except.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Personally I'd be more worried about having a bare `except` than in calling the same function from two places. You should rewrite this to catch only the exceptions that you expect to be thrown.

Comment: Note your second example is _not_ equivalent to the first, since `method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false` might itself throw an exception, causing it to be executed twice!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
class PKIsFalseException(Exception):
    pass

try: 
    pk = a_method_that_may_raise_an_exception()
    if not pk: raise PKIsFalseException()
except (PKIsFalseException, CatchableExceptions):
    method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()
```

I have updated with specific exception catching instead of catching all exceptions, which is always bad practice as others have pointed out. Assuming that your method will throw one of `CatchableExceptions`.

Comment: `assert` is only for debugging. It can be disabled, and programs are expected to run properly if `assert` is disabled.

Comment: good point.. I guess we can just raise the exception explicitly without assert for the same effect

Comment: As I commented on the post itself, a bare `except` is a bad idea. Likewise throwing `Exception()` is not good; always throw an appropriate exception. In this case something like `ValueError` might be appropriate and the `except` should then handle only the exceptions that are expected, including the one raised explicitly.

Answer (score 20):

What about something like:

```
try:
    pk = a_method_that_may_rise_an_exception()
except HandleableErrors:
    pk = False
finally:
    if pk:
        process_pk()
    else:
        method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()
```

---

Really, we don't even need the `finally` clause here...

```
try:
    pk = a_method_that_may_rise_an_exception()
except HandleableErrors:
    pk = False

if pk:
    process_pk()
else:
    method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return from the function afterwards, you could do it like this:

```
try:
    pk = a_method_that_may_rise_an_exception()
except:
    pass
else:
    if pk:
        process_pk()
        return

method_to_be_executed_in_case_of_exception_or_pk_is_false()
```